# How do I update a counter using coroutine in Unity3d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine

I'm trying to make a basic 1,2,3 go countdown but when i pass countDown to countTxt field there no changes even with for loop. I can see in  Unity inspector how the countdown works and goes from 3 to 0 but not on my text field.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class CountDown : MonoBehaviour {
public int countDown;
public Text countTxt;
public int countMax ;

void Update () {
    StartCoroutine (GetReady ());
}

IEnumerator GetReady () {
        for (countDown = countMax; countDown > 0;countDown--)
        {
            countTxt.text = countDown.ToString();
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this using a background thread?

Comment: "No changes" to what? Are you saying that the `countTxt.text` field is itself unchanged? Or that the change is not propagated to the display? Or something else? Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for advice on providing a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example, and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for advice on how to best present your question, including specific details needed to understand your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the coroutine inside Update() so its getting called all the time....it should be called in Start()

Comment: thank you! i was tired and needed someone to look at it with fresh eye